# Migrate sourceforge tickets to GitHub issues

Tags: github, sourceforge

Does anyone know of any script/package that could automatically migrate tickets in sourceforge bug/feature request trackers to GitHub issues? It's possible to export the sourceforge tickets as XML, so I would imagine that it should be possible to write a script to automatically create the tickets in GitHub, so just wanted to check if something like this exists already?

Comment: Hint for anyone looking to improve on the current answers, the SF page for exporting data (including issue tracking data!) is here: http://sourceforge.net/export/

Answer (score 5):

**Update: GitHub throttles requests through their old API, which my tool uses. https://github.com/cmungall/gosf2github uses the new API, and is probably what you want instead.**

I've written a Python script to do this. It's at https://github.com/ttencate/sf2github.

Beware: Sunday afternoon software. Use at your own risk, etc. etc. Pull requests welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The Python software foundation used [sourceforge's xml](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/XML%20export) to migrate its bug tracker to roundup, [here are the scripts](http://svn.python.org/view/tracker/importer/). For github you'd use [a REST API](http://develop.github.com/p/issues.html) or maybe something on top of that, though I didn't find a ready-made conversion script.