# Sourceforge export XML or HTML

Tags: python, sourceforge, screen-scraping, export-to-xml

I have been trying to extract and scrape information about bugs filed for the joda-time software. However, I am finding no good way to export this information to a file using an automated script or something. I do find some python scripts online but they are mostly about converting sourceforge tickets to git or outdated.

Any help in that matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shivani

Answer (score 0):

You can write a scraping script using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). You can extract the necessary information from the HTML of each bug ticket page for the joda-time software by writing some Python code with BeautifulSoup. It's not difficult and you can then do with the extracted information what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I can't understand your question.
If your question is how to extract a file as a HTML and save as a HTML

You can use **urllib** : http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are a project administrator, you have an [export to xml](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/XML%20export) option.

You also may find [Migrate sourceforge tickets to GitHub issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627241/migrate-sourceforge-tickets-to-github-issues) useful.